# TestNG unit test at maven install, install ->deploy to jetty ->start jetty ->run test -> stop server

Tags: unit-testing, maven, testng, cargo

I have a maven project.

I want to test (spring) controller class and also wrote a test class.To successfully run this test class,I want the web app to be deployed in the **(jetty )server**.

How I can achieve this, when I execute maven clean install.project is

```
    built->deployed to server->start server->run test->stop server
```

I have been looking at jetty plugin and cargo plugin but still finding it difficult to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unit test your spring controllers, you do not need to have your web application deployed to jetty.   Spring framework has testing support as documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#unit-testing-spring-mvc).

There are many examples in the web.  You can also refer to the test classes [here](http://code.google.com/p/pls-generator/source/browse/#hg/src/test/java/net/sourceforge/jukebox/web) which uses testNG.

If you do want to run tests in jetty, then refer to [these instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin#Setting_mvn_jetty%3arun_for_Automatic_Plugin_Execution_During_Unit_Testing).  Essentially you would bind the jetty start and stop to `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phases.